# Make Responsive Specific Page in Wordpress

Tags: css

Recently I created a twenty sixteen child theme and modified some script, After that my home page is no longer responsive and it look terrible in mobile.

Please help me to clarify. 
https://blockchain-labo.net/

Thanks.

Comment: which script did you modify?

Comment: twenty sixteen child theme - CSS script.

Comment: you have to explain what you exactly did.